# How to avoid passing one variable from one method to another

Tags: java, refactoring

I'm refactoring some old Java code and I'd like to know if there is a better way to refactor the following code

```
private void createControlPanel() {
  int row = 0;
  row = initSessionControls(controlPanelGB, row);
  row = initBidControls(controlPanelGB, row);
  row = initSnapshotControls(controlPanelGB, row);
}
```

row gets incremented in each method. That looks ugly to me. I also don't want to do the following

```
private void createControlPanel() {
  row = initSessionControls(controlPanelGB, 1);
  row = initBidControls(controlPanelGB, 2);
  row = initSnapshotControls(controlPanelGB, 3);
}
```

Any advice on how best to refactor this? I'm using Java 8.

Comment: Why should these methods return a new row anyway? They are not responsible for managing the row value, instead `createControlPanel` is. Also why exactly don't you want to do the second version? Because you started with "1" and not with "0" like in the first code?

Comment: Make row a filed ? (class variable). If this is what you meant in the 2nd option, there is no need to return it.

Comment: Should row belong to controlPanelGB?

Comment: this could be a perfectlly valid contract to me. If each of those methods takes the current row and returns the row where they have ended their work... That coding style enable to have methods that produce more than one row to be easily interchangeable. I can't guess if this is really the job done, but if true, then it is perfectly valid code.

Comment: if  you just want to use java8 you can try something like:            
  ```Optional.of(0)
                .map(row -> initSessionControls(controlPanelGB, row))
                .map(row -> initBidControls(controlPanelGB, row))
                .map(row -> initSnapshotControls(controlPanelGB, row))
                .get();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right to feel uncomfortable with this code. It seems that each of the called methods knows what the next row to be processed is, so they are tightly coupled and the logic for deciding the next row is distributed across several methods. Yeuch! If the next row should indeed be 1 greater that the previous row, then it's probably better to centralize this logic in the `createControlPanel` method:

```
private void createControlPanel() {
  int initialRow = 0;
  initSessionControls(controlPanelGB, initialRow);
  initBidControls(controlPanelGB, initialRow+1);
  initSnapshotControls(controlPanelGB, initialRow+2);
}
```

This is clearer than your second solution above, as it's clear that the second argument is a row, and how it relates to the initial row value.

Comment: I like this solution, like you said, it's centralized in the createControlPnael method. Thanks everyone for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a `ControlPanelFiller` class:

```
class ControlPanelFiller {
    private final ... controlPanel;
    private int row = 0;
    public ControlPanelFiller(... controlPanel) {
        this.controlPanel = controlPanel;
    }
    public ControlPanelFiller initSessionControls() {
        ...
        ++row;
        return this;
    }
    public ControlPanelFiller initBidControls() {
        ...
        ++row;
        return this;
    }
    public ControlPanelFiller initSnapshotControls() {
        ...
        ++row;
        return this;
    }
}

private void createControlPanel()
{
    ControlPanelFiller cpf = new ControlPannelFiller(controlPanelGB);
    cpf.initSessionControls()
        .initBidControls()
        .initSnapshotControls();
}
```

Comment: I'd feel this is a bit over-engineered, and you still have this fragment of duplicated code: `++row; return this;` You could avoid the duplication using a Template Method, but then it's definitely over-engineered!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below code

```
private void createControlPanel() {
int row =0;
  row += initSessionControls(controlPanelGB);
  row += initBidControls(controlPanelGB);
  row += initSnapshotControls(controlPanelGB);
}
```

Comment: This code isn't legal, e.g. `initSessionControls` should take two arguments.